# retrieve lost selection in Finder

Tags: finder

Everytime I have to manually select a lot of files by hand picking them from a big folder, I often click somewhere by accident and lose the whole selection and have to do the work all over again. I've gotten into the habit of doing this in chunks, to minimize the pain inflicted when this happens, but would like to find a better solution.

My question then is, is there some log somewhere I can query for a list of the last item selections in finder?

Or, alternatively, is there some Finder extension/alternative which kills this problem by, say, selecting files by ticking a checkbox instead?

I find the design of this has stagnated and there should be better ways on this day and age...selecting and dragging stuff around like that is fiddly and error-prone

Answer (score 1):

Try labelling them & then sort by label.